# postgresql crosstab sum columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

Currently im using LEFT JOIN between crosstab and a query. Problem is that the crosstab will sum only those columns by withc i pivoted the table. But i have 4 additional columns that also need to be summed. But crosstab just takes the first occurence and gives that. My current workaround is to do crosstab whidout these 4 columns and then a second query to get the sum columns and finally use LEFT JOIN to combine them. I want to know if there is any other way to do this.

Example:

```
id | val1 |val2 | pivot
1  | 2    | 2   | H
1  | 4    |  2  | H
1  | 3    |  3  | J
```

Result I want:

```
id| val1 | val2| H | J
1 |  9   | 7   | 2 | 1
```

Result I get using only crosstab

```
id| val1 | val2 | H |J 
1 |  2   | 2    | 2 | 1
```

Currently working needs the intial table in 2 pieces

```
id | val1 | val2
1  | 2    |  2
1  | 4    |  2
1  | 3    |  3
```

and

```
id | pivot
1  |   H
1  |   H
1  |   J
```

Normal summing query on first one and crosstab on second and then LEFT JOIN gives me the result i want.

Is there a way to use crosstab to get the result I want, or is my LEFT JOIN solution only way?